# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0

Tags: azure

I got this error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0" why trying to publish the website (+webapi) to azure. It is working properly on my machine.

web.config:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

the version of bin\system.web.http.dll  is 5.2.30128.0. Got no luck when modifying new version from 5.2.3.0 to 5.2.30128.0.

Comment: deleted all files in azure and republished the website could not solve my issue.

Comment: do you use nuget for adding this reference? If so check your packages.config file to make sure the right version is available.

Comment: tried with no sucess.
/// <summary>
    /// install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
    /// Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
    /// Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
    /// Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
    /// Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
    /// </summary>

Comment: for a reason, the System.Web.Http.dll (in published folder) is different from the one in local \bin folder. it is working after overriding the dll manually.

Comment: got failed again when republished. the solution is to delete the local folder \obj

Comment: I was getting this error after updating nuget, it was because there duplicate entry's in the web.config for System.Web.Http

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the web.config file to add assembly redirects:

```
   ....

   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding>
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>

   ...

</configuration>
```

It worked for me.